# export MYSQL_CONFIG not working with easy_install

Tags: python, environment-variables, mysql-python

So I'm trying to get MySQL setup with python. I run

```
sudo easy_install mysql-python
```

Everything goes well until I hit this roadblock:

```
Searching for mysql-python
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/mysql-python/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.3
Downloading http://download.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/mysql-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz
Running MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-n6N62W/MySQL-python-1.2.3/egg-dist-tmp-PnGsWS
sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c11', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1712, in main
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1716, in <lambda>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 476, in install_item
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 62, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 105, in run
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 64, in <lambda>
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/tmp/easy_install-n6N62W/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
  File "/tmp/easy_install-n6N62W/MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

However, I've done a

```
export MYSQL_CONFIG=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

and it seems to be there when I do a printenv. What's up with this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an easy answer to this question, see what I ended up doing here:

[MySQL-python, error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448929/mysql-python-error-command-gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-status-1)

It kind of tip toes around this problem. Don't know what is exactly wrong with easy_install.