# MySQL-python, error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, gcc, mysql-python

I've been looking around for a solution to this, and there seem to be a lot of different solutions, but none seem to be working.

I'm using MySQL-Python to try to get MySQL set up with python. But, when I try to run

```
sudo python setup.py build
```

I get the following error:

```
Password:
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql-5.5.21-osx10.6-x86/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch i386
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/unicodeobject.h:4,
             from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:85,
             from pymemcompat.h:10,
             from _mysql.c:29:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include/stdarg.h:4:25: error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.21-osx10.6-x86/include/my_config.h:329:1: warning: "SIZEOF_SIZE_T" redefined
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:9,
             from pymemcompat.h:10,
             from _mysql.c:29:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:56:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.21-osx10.6-x86/include/my_config.h:422:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
In file included from     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:8,
             from pymemcompat.h:10,
             from _mysql.c:29:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:887:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: "a lot of different solutions, but none seem to be working".  Please be specific.  What ones have you tried?  What happened?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473066/gcc-4-2-failed-with-exit-status-1, Same error followed

Comment: Also http://justcramer.com/2007/11/05/mysqldb-on-leopard/, but I didn't even find the lines they were talking about, and the error didn't seem to be exactly the same

Comment: @S.Lott all the other solutions seem to be variations on those two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. After a few hours of struggling, I've used ActivePython (http://code.activestate.com/pypm/mysql-python/) successfully to install MySQL-python. Although it doesn't exactly solve your error, it solves the overall issue :)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I just ended up using SQLite temporarily, but I figured this is just one of those times when you have to try to install something different.